# CONCAT + TRIM no longer working after encryption

Tags: php, sql, database, concatenation, trim

Since encrypting certain information in my database I am having a great deal of difficulty using an existing search function. Its function is to search a table of students by either first, last or both names.

The old working code is as follows:

```
SELECT *
FROM students
WHERE CONCAT(TRIM(firstname), ' ', TRIM(lastname)) LIKE '%$result%'
AND currentyear = $currentyear
ORDER BY students.lastname
```

The new non working code following encryption:

```
SELECT *, 
       AES_DECRYPT(firstname,UNHEX(SHA2('',512))) AS stfirst,
       AES_DECRYPT(lastname,UNHEX(SHA2('',512))) AS stlast
FROM students
WHERE CONCAT(TRIM(stfirst), ' ', TRIM(stlast)) LIKE '%$result%'
AND currentyear = $currentyear
ORDER BY stlast
```

Am I missing something really stupid here? Thank you.

Comment: Please don't passwords and change them in your live instance now.

Comment: Why did you encrypt the data in tables ? Queries used now will be very inefficient, and won't be able to use indexing

Comment: I had to encrypt the data for new European GDPR regulations.

Comment: Still, might make more sense to split your `$result` into two(?) parts instead, and encrypted those, so that you can compare them to the already encrypted column contents … (That might leave the issue of trimming, but why was that not applied when the data was _inserted_ to begin with? If neglected at that point, maybe time to fire a decrypt-trim-encrypt update query now first of all.)

Comment: Please tag with the database you are using.

Comment: On-fly encryption was a stupid idea in the first place. There are plugins (for InnoDB for instance) which encrypt entire tables on the file level.

Answer (score 0):

you can't use select alias name in where condition  .. you should repeat the code

and if you want compare encrypted  values  you should also encypt the matching value

and last try using concat('%', $result,'%')  instead of '%$result%'

```
SELECT *
  , AES_DECRYPT(firstname,UNHEX(SHA2('',512))) AS stfirst
  , AES_DECRYPT(lastname,UNHEX(SHA2('',512))) AS stlast
FROM students
WHERE CONCAT(TRIM(AES_DECRYPT(firstname,UNHEX(SHA2('',512)))), ' ', 
              TRIM(AES_DECRYPT(lastname,UNHEX(SHA2('',512))))) 
              LIKE TRIM(AES_DECRYPT( concat('%', $result,'%'),
                          UNHEX(SHA2('',512)))))
AND currentyear = $currentyear
ORDER BY stlast
```

Comment: I had tried this and have just done so again but that isn't working either I'm afraid.

Comment: what mean "is not working"  ?... you have error ? show error message .. wrong result? show the expected  result and you actual result

Comment: No error message, the code works but it is delivering 0 results. As I said earlier the issue has only stopped working since I have been using encrypted data. It appears to be an issue with the decryption.

Comment: Remove the WHERE clause, and see if the values you selected under the aliases  `stfirst` and `stlast` contain properly “decoded” names as you expect …?

Comment: @PhilHowell   .. answer  updated ..  (anyway seems strange that the where work using alias)

Comment: I think the issue may well be with the WHERE clause as when I run the following code I am still left with 0 results even though I know there are several students with the last name 'baker':

SELECT * FROM students WHERE lastname = AES_ENCRYPT('baker',UNHEX(SHA2('',512)))

Comment: Thank you for your help but I'm afraid this doesn't work either!

Comment: show me the content of $result and the content of firstname or firstname  .. as saved  on db  ... be sure also  that you are using a valid currentyear

Comment: FYI the search result has not been encrypted and doesn't need to be. The same result interacts with another table of data that isn't encrypted so it really isn't an option.

Comment: if you don't need  encryption on where  .. then why you are using ..?

Comment: The same $result is used in another query to search unencrypted fields. I have two main tables of data that form the structure of the database. Only one of those two tables contains sensitive information which has to be encrypted due to GDPR. However, the search bar is used to search information from both tables. $currentyear isn't a problem. Perhaps the answer is to encrypt $result and then compare that way?

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, you are using MySQL.  If so, MySQL extends SQL so you can use a `HAVING` clause with column aliases,  So, you can write the query as:

```
SELECT s.*, 
       AES_DECRYPT(firstname,UNHEX(SHA2('', 512))) AS stfirst,
       AES_DECRYPT(lastname,UNHEX(SHA2('', 512))) AS stlast
FROM students s
WHERE currentyear = $currentyear
HAVING CONCAT(TRIM(stfirst), ' ', TRIM(stlast)) LIKE '%$result%' 
ORDER BY stlast;
```